# PTIJ: Pay? How much? And which cow?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Every year, right around when Adar begins, one of my Rebbeim would let us know that we need to

## Pay to Remember the Cow of the Month

Well, Adar came around this year (twice!), and when I went ahead with trying to follow my Rebbi's advice, I stopped cold and realized: I don't know what I'm supposed to do! He said to pay, but to who, and how much? The cow? Which cow? And 'the Month' is (probably?) Adar, but which one? And so many other questions that I can't even begin to list out (but feel free to elaborate on in your answer)! So please, if you know what needs to be done, let me know so I can fulfill the Mitzvah of listening to the teachings of my Rebbi!

---

<sub><sub>When I asked my Chavrusa what our Rebbi meant, he said "Really? It's clearly a [mnemonic device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic) used to remember the order of [The Four Parshios](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Four_Parshiot)." Or something like that. I wasn't really paying attention to what he said since I had started calculating the English gematrias of each of the words to see if maybe there was something deep and mystical I was overlooking.</sub></sub>

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

- The *egel ha'zahav* was *stolen* from the *kisei ha'kavod*.
- All *onshim* that come onto the *benei yisrael* are because of the *egel ha'zahav*.
- Each Rosh Chodesh we seek to annul this *midas ha'din* by using the *tziruf* of the *shem ha'vayah* of that month for the middle *berachah* in *mussaf*.
- If you have *meshulachim* annoying you, you won't be able to concentrate on the correct *tzeruf* of the *shem ha'vahayah*, so you have to pay off the *meshulachim* to be able to remember the *tikkun* of that *middas ha'din* which would be *sholet* in that particular month.

Answer (score 0):

["The Forward"](https://forward.com/scribe/395291/a-shtetl-cow-named-vashti/) has an article about a cow named Vashti.

As we all know Vashti was a free spirit and did what she wanted and did not care what her husband said.

Thus if you would want to milk Vashti you would have to pay for this honor.

This would apply any month of the year, not only in Adar.